# Create Node for linkedlist C++

Tags: c++

I'm working on implementing linked list using c++. I created a struct Node inside my LinkedList.h, and try to overload operator in node. But when I compiled, I got this error
Code:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

class LinkedList{
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
} * nodePtr;

//Returns true if the current Node object value is 
//less than the parameter Node object value 
bool operator < (const Node& node) const {
    return this->data < node->data;          <--- Unable to resolve identifier data.
};
#endif  /* LINKEDLIST_H */
```

I don't know what I did wrong. Can someone tell me please?! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although I would do this differently, the problem is that you don't define any place in your class to hold a Node structure. I'm not sure if you were trying for this or not:

```
class LinkedList{
    typedef struct Node{
        int data;
        Node* next;
    } * nodePtr;

    Node node; // Added this

    //Returns true if the current Node object value is
    //less than the parameter Node object value
    bool operator < (const Node& node) const {
        return this->node.data < node.data;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to access something that doesn't exist.  Your `LinkedList` implementation doesn't have a variable named `data`.

The simplest fix is to change your `operator` body:

```
return this->nodePtr->data < node->data;
```

However, I would suggest refactoring to have a full separate class for `Node`; you can put the operator overload in that class.

Comment: return this->nodePtr->data < node->data; I tried this, but still have the same problem